# How to get data out of a mib file with sharpsnmp?

Tags: compilation, snmp, mib

I can't figure out how to parse mib files with sharpsnmp, could someone point me to a resource?

Answer (score 0):

The official way of doing so is via SharpSnmpPro.Mib, which is a commercial product,

https://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SharpSnmpPro.Mib

Comment: hm this still doesnt help me i mean in the situation that i have a mib file and i want to open it in a form that i can extract the data from it how do i do it with sharpsnmp. Also the code gives me missing namespaces for ErrorRegistry and registry.Tree doesnt contain Collector

Comment: SharpSnmpPro.Mib is different from SharpSnmpLib.Mib, so "missing namespace" is expected.